# Network images are not displayed in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter

I have used canvaskit Web Renderer for the build
But the images I get from the network are not displayed

When I use html Web Renderer , the images are displayed well, but the custom fonts are not loaded.
And there are other problems with the show
So I need to use canvaskit Web Renderer.
Now how can I display my pictures?

Comment: What error are you seeing in the Developer Tools / Network tab?

Comment: please read the docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/web-images